# Add nodepool to an existing AKS cluster via ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-aks, azure-rm-template, azure-sdk-.net

I have an existing AKS cluster ( i know the name and other details of it)

Is it possible to add an extra nodepool to the existing AKS cluster using ARM Templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to add an extra node pool to the existing AKS cluster using ARM Templates?

***Yes, it is possible to add an extra Node Pool to the existing AKS cluster.***

### Manage node pools using a Resource Manager template

You can typically alter the settings in your template and redeploy to update the resource when you use an ARM template to generate and manage resources. The initial node pool profile for node pools in AKS cannot be changed once the AKS cluster has been set up. Due to this behavior, you are unable to modify an existing Resource Manager template, alter the node pools, and then redeploy. The only thing that needs to be updated for an existing AKS cluster is the node pools, thus you must instead construct a different Resource Manager template.

Make a template like `aks-agentpools.json` and paste the sample manifest underneath it. The following settings are configured by this sample template:

- `_myagentpool_`, named as a Linux node pool, is updated to support three nodes.
- creates a node pool with nodes running `Kubernetes version 1.15.7`.
- node size --> *Standard_DS2_v2*.

Update, add, or remove node pools by editing these variables as necessary:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "clusterName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "existing AKS Cluster Name."
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "existing AKS Cluster location."
            }
        },
        "agentPoolName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "myagentpool",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "agent pool name to create or update."
            }
        },
        "vnetSubnetId": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The Virtual network subnet resource ID for the existing AKS cluster."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "apiVersion": {
            "aks": "2020-01-01"
        },
        "agentPoolProfiles": {
            "maxPods": 30,
            "osDiskSizeGB": 0,
            "agentCount": 3,
            "agentVmSize": "Standard_DS2_v2",
            "osType": "Linux",
            "vnetSubnetId": "[parameters('vnetSubnetId')]"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2020-01-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/agentPools",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('clusterName'),'/', parameters('agentPoolName'))]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "maxPods": "[variables('agentPoolProfiles').maxPods]",
                "osDiskSizeGB": "[variables('agentPoolProfiles').osDiskSizeGB]",
                "count": "[variables('agentPoolProfiles').agentCount]",
                "vmSize": "[variables('agentPoolProfiles').agentVmSize]",
                "osType": "[variables('agentPoolProfiles').osType]",
                "storageProfile": "ManagedDisks",
                "type": "VirtualMachineScaleSets",
                "vnetSubnetID": "[variables('agentPoolProfiles').vnetSubnetId]",
                "orchestratorVersion": "1.15.7"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Use the [az deployment group create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/deployment/group?view=azure-cli-latest&preserve-view=true#az_deployment_group_create) command to deploy this template, as demonstrated in the example below:

**--Azure CLI**

```
az deployment group create \
    --resource-group testrg \
    --template-file aks-agentpools.json
```

Refer to the [Manage Node Pools in an existing AKS Cluster using ARM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/aks/use-multiple-node-pools#manage-node-pools-using-a-resource-manager-template) for more details, provided by Microsoft.

---

**Also,**

### To add a dedicated system node pool to an existing AKS cluster

Existing AKS clusters can add one or more system node pools.

The next command creates a mode type system with a dedicated node pool with a default node count of three.

```
az aks nodepool add \
    --resource-group testrg \
    --cluster-name testAKSCluster \
    --name systempool \
    --node-count 3 \
    --node-taints CriticalAddonsOnly=true:NoSchedule \
    --mode System
```

References:

1. Adding the dedicated system, refer to the Microsoft's Doc of [usingSystemPools-in-existing-AKS-Cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-system-pools)]
2. **Azure Node Pool** creation using **ARM Template**, refer to this [**[MSFT Documentation]](https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/cli/ext/aks-preview/aks/nodepool?view=azure-cli-latest)** which gives you clear idea about each command.
3. **[Deploy AKS with Node Pools and AAD authentication using ARM Templates](https://pixelrobots.co.uk/2020/01/deploy-aks-with-node-pools-and-aad-authentication-using-arm-templates/)**, refer here - provided by Pixel Robots.